# I want to have a prometheus query which is filtering based on all type of labels and then grouping it based on instance

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

```
100 - (sum(node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/tmp"}) by (instance)/(sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/tmp"}) by (instance))* 100)
```

this gives me: the percentage of file usage on a particular mount ie tmp grouped per instance
[output of prom query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7irle.png)

But what I need is some regex or some way to have % on tmp var opt and everything grouped per instance. I don't want to write separate queries for each. Is there a way to achieve this?
So I have currently is.

tmp node A percentage
tmp node B percentage

what I want is.

tmp node A percentage
tmp node B percentage
var node A percentage
var node B percentage
and so on.

In a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "mountpoint="/tmp"" and add "mountpoint" in the "by" clause:

```
100 - (sum(node_filesystem_avail_bytes) by (instance, mountpoint)/(sum(node_filesystem_size_bytes) by (instance, mountpoint))* 100)
```

Comment: This gives the value for all file systems as same. Like for all mount points it shows 73%

Comment: Weird, it worked pretty well for me.